# Trouble locating the clickable website element for a multidivisional button for selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have a surface level of HTML so please bare with me on my word selection and feel free to critique in the comments to improve the clarity of the question.

I am trying to click a button using Selenium webdriver with Python. It is visible, but I cannot figure out which element in the HTML to select. I have been right-clicking, hitting inspect element on the page's visible element and then locating a corresponding element to use with either `By.ID` or `By.CLASS` but in this case I have been having trouble locating the element to click on to. When I click inspect the element, this button seems to be more complicated than the other buttons I have encountered and the button that appears on the screen has several divisions in the HTML. I have attached what it looks like from the GUI view:

[image: GUI view of button]

I cannot link the whole website as it requires a username and password but below is a snippet of the HTML for the button of interest on the site is as follows:

```html
</div></div></div>
<div  style=''  class='content-item content-sub_section item-2    margin-b-2x flex flex-row ' NAME='BASE_REF' BASE_REF='D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)'  data-test-id='202006181513580955512-2'  STRING_TYPE='sub_section' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
<div  class='sectionDivStyle  ' style='' id='RULE_KEY' node_type='MAIN_RULE' node_name='PortalTiles' data-node-id='PortalTiles' version='1' objclass='Rule-HTML-Section'  pyclassname='NJJ-Data-' readonly='false'  NAME='BASE_REF' BASE_REF='' expandRL='true' INDEX='2' uniqueID='SID1698765168490' >
<div id="CT" SWP=".IsSubMenu,.App_order,.App_ID"  SHOW_WHEN=".IsSubMenu != true && .App_order!=-1 && .App_ID != 'AOCMF'" data-simplelayout = "true"  style=' '>
   <div class='layout layout-noheader layout-noheader-all_cases_tile has-action '>
      <div section_index='2' class=' layout-body'>
         <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  pointer  layout-content-simple_list_fixed content-simple_list_fixed margin-b-2x'    data-click='[["runScript", ["launchNewBrowserTab(\"#~D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2).AppHomeURL~#\")"]]]'  >
            <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
               <div class='layout layout-none'>
                  <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                     <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-inline content-inline width-100-pct padding-1x fixed-height-40 nowrap'    >
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                           <div class='layout layout-none'>
                              <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                                 <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default fixed-height-40'    >
                                    <div  style=''  class='content-item content-label item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    width-100-pct left-aligned dataLabelWrite tile_label_dataLabelWrite flex flex-row ' data-test-id='20200511150809067558141' STRING_TYPE='label' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>eCourts</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-2 remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                           <div class='layout layout-none'>
                              <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                                 <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default '    >
                                    <div id="CT" SWP=".IsSubMenu"  SHOW_WHEN=".IsSubMenu=='true'" style='display:none; '  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    color-primary dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='false'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200629171622057167999'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class=' icons fas fa-ellipsis-v' tabindex='0' role='link' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_23' alt= '' data-click='[["showMenu",[{"dataSource":"TileSubMenu", "isNavNLDeferLoaded":"false", "isNavTypeCustom":"false", "className":"NJJ-Data-","menuAlign":"left","format":"menu-format-standard-tabbed" , "loadBehavior":"ondisplay", "ellipsisAfter":"999","usingPage":"D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)", "useNewMenu":"true", "isMobile":"false", "navPageName":"pyNavigation1677611935770"},":event"]]]'  ></i></span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-2 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
               <div class='layout layout-none'>
                  <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                     <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-stacked content-stacked width-100-pct centered padding-1x fixed-height-108'    >
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    tile-icon width-100-pct centered dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='false'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200511150809067661321'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class='cursordefault  icons far fa-file-signature' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_26' alt= '' ></i></span></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-3 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
               <div class='layout layout-none'>
                  <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                     <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-inline content-inline width-100-pct padding-r-1x fixed-height-40'    >
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                           <div class='layout layout-none'>
                              <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                                 <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default '    >
                                    <div  style=''  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    label-color dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='true'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200511150809067764740'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class='cursordefault  icons far fa-external-link' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_31' title= 'Opens in new browser tab '  alt= 'Opens in new browser tab '  ></i></span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="CT" SWP=".IsSubMenu,.App_order"  SHOW_WHEN=".IsSubMenu=='true' && .App_order!=-1" data-simplelayout = "true"  style='display:none; '>
   <div class='layout layout-noheader layout-noheader-all_cases_tile has-action '>
      <div section_index='3' class=' layout-body'>
         <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  pointer  layout-content-simple_list_fixed content-simple_list_fixed margin-b-2x'    data-click='[["showMenu",[{"dataSource":"TileSubMenu", "isNavNLDeferLoaded":"false", "isNavTypeCustom":"false", "className":"NJJ-Data-","menuAlign":"left","format":"menu-format-standard-tabbed" , "loadBehavior":"ondisplay", "ellipsisAfter":"999","usingPage":"D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)", "useNewMenu":"true", "isMobile":"false", "navPageName":"pyNavigation1677611935818"},":event"]]]'  >
            <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
               <div class='layout layout-none'>
                  <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                     <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-inline content-inline width-100-pct padding-1x fixed-height-40 nowrap'    >
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                           <div class='layout layout-none'>
                              <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                                 <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default fixed-height-40'    >
                                    <div  style=''  class='content-item content-label item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    width-100-pct left-aligned dataLabelWrite tile_label_dataLabelWrite flex flex-row ' data-test-id='20200511150809067558141' STRING_TYPE='label' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>eCourts</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-2 remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                           <div class='layout layout-none'>
                              <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                                 <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default '    >
                                    <div id="CT" SWP=".IsSubMenu"  SHOW_WHEN=".IsSubMenu=='true'" style='display:none; '  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    color-primary dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='false'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200629171622057167999'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class=' icons fas fa-ellipsis-v' tabindex='0' role='link' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_40' alt= '' data-click='[["showMenu",[{"dataSource":"TileSubMenu", "isNavNLDeferLoaded":"false", "isNavTypeCustom":"false", "className":"NJJ-Data-","menuAlign":"left","format":"menu-format-standard-tabbed" , "loadBehavior":"ondisplay", "ellipsisAfter":"999","usingPage":"D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)", "useNewMenu":"true", "isMobile":"false", "navPageName":"pyNavigation1677611935842"},":event"]]]'  ></i></span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-2 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
               <div class='layout layout-none'>
                  <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                     <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-stacked content-stacked width-100-pct centered padding-1x fixed-height-108'    >
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    tile-icon width-100-pct centered dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='false'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200511150809067661321'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class='cursordefault  icons far fa-file-signature' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_43' alt= '' ></i></span></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-3 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
               <div class='layout layout-none'>
                  <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                     <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-inline content-inline width-100-pct padding-r-1x fixed-height-40'    >
                        <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                           <div class='layout layout-none'>
                              <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                                 <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default '    >
                                    <div  style=''  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    label-color dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='true'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200511150809067764740'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class='cursordefault  icons far fa-external-link' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_48' title= 'Opens in new browser tab '  alt= 'Opens in new browser tab '  ></i></span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="CT" SWP=".IsSubMenu,.App_order,.App_ID"  SHOW_WHEN=".IsSubMenu != true && .App_order!=-1 && .App_ID = 'AOCMF'" data-simplelayout = "true"  style='display:none; '>
<div class='layout layout-noheader layout-noheader-all_cases_tile has-action '>
   <div section_index='4' class=' layout-body'>
      <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  pointer  layout-content-simple_list_fixed content-simple_list_fixed margin-b-2x'    data-click='[["runScript", ["OpenEntPortalTerminalEmulation()"]]]'  >
         <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
            <div class='layout layout-none'>
               <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                  <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-inline content-inline width-100-pct padding-1x fixed-height-40 nowrap'    >
                     <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                        <div class='layout layout-none'>
                           <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                              <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default fixed-height-40'    >
                                 <div  style=''  class='content-item content-label item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    width-100-pct left-aligned dataLabelWrite tile_label_dataLabelWrite flex flex-row ' data-test-id='20200511150809067558141' STRING_TYPE='label' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>eCourts</div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-2 remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                        <div class='layout layout-none'>
                           <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                              <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default '    >
                                 <div id="CT" SWP=".IsSubMenu"  SHOW_WHEN=".IsSubMenu=='true'" style='display:none; '  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    color-primary dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='false'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200629171622057167999'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class=' icons fas fa-ellipsis-v' tabindex='0' role='link' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_57' alt= '' data-click='[["showMenu",[{"dataSource":"TileSubMenu", "isNavNLDeferLoaded":"false", "isNavTypeCustom":"false", "className":"NJJ-Data-","menuAlign":"left","format":"menu-format-standard-tabbed" , "loadBehavior":"ondisplay", "ellipsisAfter":"999","usingPage":"D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)", "useNewMenu":"true", "isMobile":"false", "navPageName":"pyNavigation1677611935910"},":event"]]]'  ></i></span></div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-2 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
            <div class='layout layout-none'>
               <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                  <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-stacked content-stacked width-100-pct centered padding-1x fixed-height-108'    >
                     <div  style=''  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    tile-icon width-100-pct centered dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='false'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200511150809067661321'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class='cursordefault  icons far fa-file-signature' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_60' alt= '' ></i></span></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-3 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
            <div class='layout layout-none'>
               <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                  <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-inline content-inline width-100-pct padding-r-1x fixed-height-40'    >
                     <div  style=''  class='content-item content-layout item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing   flex flex-row  align-end'  STRING_TYPE='layout' RESERVE_SPACE='false'>
                        <div class='layout layout-none'>
                           <div section_index='1' class=' layout-body'>
                              <div bSimpleLayout='true'  class='flex  content  layout-content-default content-default '    >
                                 <div  style=''  class='content-item content-field item-1 remove-top-spacing remove-left-spacing remove-bottom-spacing remove-right-spacing    label-color dataValueWrite flex flex-row '  STRING_TYPE='field' RESERVE_SPACE='true'><span ><i  data-test-id='20200511150809067764740'  href='' onclick='pd(event);' data-ctl='Icon'  class='cursordefault  icons far fa-external-link' name='PortalTiles_D_PortalTiles.PortalTiles(2)_65' title= 'Opens in new browser tab '  alt= 'Opens in new browser tab '  ></i></span></div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas to which element I would target to click on the button and how you knew which one to select? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.